# Bash how to initialize variable and output its value to file in one line

Tags: bash, shell

```
PV=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' exec:exec)
PV >> test.txt
```

I'd like to turn this into a one-liner so it will both initialize the variable and output its value to `test.txt`.

Something like this, but it's not working:

```
PV=$($(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' exec:exec)) >> test.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **tee** command

```
PV=$(echo XXX | tee test.txt)
```

Now text.txt contains **XXX** and variable PV's value is **XXX** as well.
In your case I guess the command should be:

```
PV=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' exec:exec | tee test.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be really unnatural to try to do both in one line. Use two lines. Note that `PV >> test.txt` doesn't work. You need an `echo` in there:

```
PV=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' exec:exec)
echo "$PV" >> test.txt
```

If you really want to do it in one line you can use `tee`, but I don't recommend it. Two lines are easier to read.

```
PV=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' exec:exec | tee -a test.txt)
```